# Does terraform `google_cloudfunctions_function` run build during deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am using terraform to deploy cloud function to GCP (nodejs) and below is my configuration:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "identity" {
  name        = "${var.stage}-${local.app_name}-identity"
  description = "GCP Identity"
  runtime     = "nodejs16"

  available_memory_mb   = 512
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = "addUserRoles"

}
```

When run `terraform apply` I got below error:

```
google_cloudfunctions_function.identity: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
google_cloudfunctions_function.identity: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
google_cloudfunctions_function.identity: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
google_cloudfunctions_function.identity: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Error waiting for Creating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Build failed: yarn install v1.22.19
│ [1/5] Validating package.json...
│ [2/5] Resolving packages...
│ [3/5] Fetching packages...
│ error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npco.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dev-local/@company/eslint-config/-/@company/eslint-config-1.0.5.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
│ info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/workspace/yarn-error.log".
│ info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.; Error ID: 12c8ef4a
│ 
│   with google_cloudfunctions_function.identity,
│   on function.tf line 17, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "identity":
│   17: resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "identity" {
│
```

I seems like running `terraform` deploy which run `yarn install` automatically. The code has been built and published to the storage bucket specified in the configure. Why does it still install dependencies?

If there is any automatic build happens during deployment, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a Cloud Functions with Terraform, it's similar to a [ZIP deployment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-cloud-storage)

As any Cloud Functions deployment, Cloud Build is invoked with Buildpack to create a container (it that step, the dependencies are downloaded and installed, the code packaged/compiled (according to the language),...). Once the container built, it is deployed on Cloud Functions.

---

So YES, Terraform runs a Cloud Functions build with Cloud Build when you deploy your Cloud Functions.

If you have an issue and instead of using Terraform, you can use the Deploy from Cloud Storage option in Cloud Functions to test and iterate on it.

Comment: Do you mean I can't let terraform skip compiling during deployment?

Comment: Terraform do nothing! It invoke the Cloud Functions deployment from Cloud Storage feature. The rest is the standard Cloud Functions deployment process. You can't skip it, except if you don't want to deploy your function

Comment: oh, I would say it is pretty a bad design. I want to deploy the code which has been compiled and tested. It seems every time GCP compiles it from scratch during deployment.

Comment: So, you don't use the correct product! Have a look to Cloud Run. You can build your container (with your code and all the things) separately (before the terraform in fact), and then reference that container in your terraform. No new build this time, the container is already built. Only a deployment (if required)